# yarn install does not create yarn.lock lockfile

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I find lock files annoying during dev, great for prod.

In my `.npmrc` I have:

```
package-lock=false
```

Which prevents npm from creating a `package-lock.json` file during an `npm install`.

Yarn however does not respect this and still creates `yarn.lock` during a `yarn install`.

Is there a similar `.yarnrc` setting that will prevent yarn creating the `yarn.lock` lockfile? I'm tired of deleting it!

Or maybe it's OK to leave it there? I know when an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file is present `package.json` is totally ignored. I do not want this. Is this the same for `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` or do they work differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `--no-lockfile` flag which you can also add to your .yarnrc in [this format](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarnrc/):

```
--install.no-lockfile true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ::-

```
yarn add no-lockfile true
```